# Django, ManyToMany, checking the value

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble understanding `ManyToMany` field in django

I have this model

```
class Courses_list(models.Model):
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.abbreviation

class Job_Posting(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Job Post'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Job Posts'

    job= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    the_courses = models.ManyToManyField(Courses_list, verbose_name="Courses")
```

How do I check `the_courses` content?

What I did is:

```
a = Job_Posting.objects.get(pk=1)
if "MSIT" in a.the_courses.all():
    print "Success"
```

But I can't seem to make it work, What am I doing wrong?
Sorry if it is a bit unclear, I don't really know how to explain my problem.

Comment: `a.the_courses.filter(abbreviation='MSIT')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare the content of an object, with the object itself.

`a.the_courses.all()` returns a queryset (like a list of objects).

An alternate way of testing what you are looking for is:

```
if a.the_courses.filter(abbreviation="MSIT").exists():
    print "Success"
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding that ManyToMany is just like querying. :)